# Validate Array with vee-validation useForm and useField

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vee-validate

I use vee validation useField and useForm
Help me split errorMessage on array, right now errorMessage show me one error. And when i change one input, errorMessage show me another one error. But i need to show all errors
How change this code?

I use:

"vee-validate": "^4.2.3",

"vue": "^3.0.0",

"yup": "^0.32.9"

```js
<script lang='ts'>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '@/store'
// import { AllMutationTypes } from '@/store/mutations-type'
import { useField, useForm } from 'vee-validate'
import * as yup from 'yup'
export default defineComponent({
  emits: ['created'],
  setup () {
    const item: any = [{
      name: 'Я тут',
      freq: 1,
      bg: '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6)
    },
    {
      name: 'Был тут',
      freq: 1,
      bg: '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6)
    }
    ]

    const { isSubmitting, handleSubmit } = useForm({
      initialValues: {
        itemsWheel: item
      }
    })

    const { value: itemsWheel, errorMessage: iError, handleBlur: iBlur } : any = useField(
      'itemsWheel',
      yup
        .array()
        .of(
          yup.object().shape({
            name: yup.string().required(),
            freq: yup.number().positive(').integer().required(),
            bg: yup.string()
          })
        )
        .strict()
    )

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async values => {
      console.log(values.itemsWheel)
    })

    return {
      addItemOfWheel,
      deleteItem,
      itemsWheel,
      iError,
      iBlur,
      isSubmitting,
      onSubmit
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit()">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-of-Wheel" v-for="(item, index) in itemsWheel" :key="index" @blur="iBlur">
         <div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" @change="change" v-model="item.name"/>
        </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" @click="item.freq+=1">+</button>
            <input class="freq" type="number" v-model.number="item.freq">
            <button type="button" @click="item.freq > 1 ? item.freq-=1 : null" min="1">-</button>
          </div>
          <input type="color" v-model="item.bg" />
          <button type="button" @click="deleteItem(index)">Удалить</button>
      </li>
      <small >{{ iError }}</small>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" :disabled="isSubmitting" >Создать Колесо</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! try to 1. check your text for correct English, so it comes clear what you mean - punctuation is our friend :) 2. as we ask questions on SO, try to formulate a specific question , so we can answer and help you to solve your problem. 3. try not to post all your sourcecode but the specific parts that are involved in the issue :)